# add extra parameters to Permission tab (Liferay 6.2 Configuration)

Tags: configuration, liferay

Is there any way to add extra column to Permission tab in Configuration setting of Portlet? I have a portlet which allows adding and editing of some documents. So i need to set some configuration such as Allow Add / Edit to user based on their roles.

I read about "Implementing Configurable Portlet Preferences" in the documentation section of Liferay. It adds an extra setup tab where we can specify some settings. However if i need to add some extra columns/parameters in existing tab, i am not sure how to do it. If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is you are looking for additional permissions in the permissions tab. In order to achieve the same check out - https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/security-and-permissions

Let me know in case of any doubts.

Comment: Yeah i defined some action keys inside a xml file and placed it inside reource actions folder. Later checked the permssion using Liferays permission checker. It worked Thanks!!

Comment: Do you know how i can set permission for a portlet based on domain. For example we are using some portlets on two different websites. Are there any specific settings on liferay?